# Make buttons (hyperlink) same-size as child in parent wrapper without width or max-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I made a codepen example which shows my problem pretty good: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGQNrP
(Link will open in same window)

I can make as many wrappers as I want to, but the hyperlink itself has to be in the button wrapper. So I think my markup would look like this:

```
<div class="triggered">
  <div class="button">
    <a href="">Small</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="">Large Large Large</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried many things with flex and grid but I just can't get it to work.
I don't want to use width, max-width, table-row or something like this.
Flex or grid would be really nice, at least I'm really intereseted in howto get it done with flex or grid.

Comment: don’t use grid for this. Flex is made for one dimensional layouts and Grid is made for two dimensional layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the container element `inline-block`, and the links themselves `block` …?

```
.triggered {
  display: inline-block;
  & .button {
    margin: 1rem 0;

    & a {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 1rem;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJeNxd

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why I wasn't able to figure it out by myself. That is embarrassing, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can make `.triggered` a `inline-flex` and set the `flex-direction` to `column` and make the `a` tag `display:block;` so it fills the whole width of `.triggered`

```
.triggered {
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;  

  & .button {
    margin: 1rem 0;  

    & a {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 1rem;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```